# conditional strsplit

Tags: regex, r

I have a dataframe where one of the columns contains a set of names. I would like to stringsplit a portion of the column names and have done so as follows:

```
DF$newname <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(DF$oldname), "_"), '[', 5)
```

in this example the fifth part of the split contains the name part of the character string. The problem is that this dataset contains `$oldname` names that are in different formats. In the first format the name is as follows where XXX are numbers:

```
xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_name_xx  (name is in fifth position)
```

and the second format the `$oldname` looks like this

```
xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_name_xx  (name is in sixth position)
```

I was thinking that I could use an `ifelse` command from within a function but am running into a little bit of trouble with the following code:

```
namesplit = function(df){ 
  x <- strsplit(as.character(df$oldname), "_"), '[', 5)
  y <- strsplit(as.character(df$oldname), "_"), '[', 6)
  ifelse(is.character(x),x,y) }
DF$newname <- sapply(DF,namesplit)
```

this code doesn't work as I know I can's use the `[` in this way but I am not sure of the best way. while I think I could get this working within a `for` loop, I would prefer to find a way to extract the names in a way that would allow me to use an `apply`.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this using `gsub`

```
names <- c('xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_name1_xx', 'xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_name2_xx')
gsub("^.*_([[:alnum:]]+)_.*$", "\\1", names)


[1] "name1" "name2"
```

Comment: thank you Ramnath. FOrt his example I've simplified the names a little bit (they are derived from FASTA headers that have a mix of character and numeric data. when I apply this method to the real dataset it does not always apply a true value. I would prefer to include an 'ifelse' so that I can expand this for future datasets which may have another format.

Comment: but.... i think you are right. I should be able to tweak your solution just a little bit to get what I need.

Comment: if you are parsing FASTA headers, check out the code on this blog which uses `C` and `R` to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

If the name is the penultimate portion how about this:

```
x <- c("xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_name_xx", "xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_name_xx")


namesplit = function(x){
x <- strsplit(as.character(x), "_")
sapply(x, function(x) x[length(x)-1])
}
```

HTH

Comment: I like this method except that for a subset of the names the names have multiple words that are separated by the '"_"' character. SO counting from the end will be inconsistent. Thank you , though!

Comment: @zach, So how do you expect to split it when you splitting with "_" will also split your name?

Comment: the names are chemical names. the first part of the name is the most important. the other parts are not important but will interfere with the counting backwards. This dataset was given to me so in the future I will separate the chemical names with a different character. One name might be "Tyrosine" and another "Proline_Alpha". I would only care about the primary name. I am sorry if the question was misleading.